# Regex to match a single word in url

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm new to Regex in Javascript and I'm trying to get a pattern that allows me to get a specific word in the urls from my website.

I have these sample urls:

- http://www.mysite.com/site/firstsection/sections/index.html
- http://www.mysite.com/site/sectionwithanyname/sections/promotions/register.html
- http://www.mysite.com/site/anothersection/subscribe/myname/logo.html

I need a pattern that return the single word between http://www.mysite.com/site/ and /index.html in the first url, that means "firstsection" returned, "sectionwithanyname" and so on.

```
<p>Any help is very apreciated!!!</p>

<p>Thanks a lot!!!</p>
```

Comment: I've been playing with Gskinner RegExr trying to match the word, but I have not been close :(

Comment: It would have been better if you had put your closest regex in your question. Or maybe a couple of regex you have tried.

Comment: are you sure that you want "firstsection" and not "firstsection/sections"?

Comment: One of the regex I´ve been trying is this (http://www.mysite.com/site/)^firstsection$(/sections/index.html)

Comment: i need the specific word "firstsection"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
var ur='http://www.mysite.com/site/firstsection/sections/index.html';
var ur1='http://www.mysite.com/site/sectionwithanyname/sections/promotions/register.html'
var link = ur.split('/');
var link1 = ur1.split('/');
alert(link[4]);//alert'firstsection'
alert(link1[4]);//alert'sectionwithanyname'
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C6B4K/)

Comment: thanks a lot, but I need a more generic method because I'm testing in different environments, and they have different amounts of "/" characters